# How do I get flash to reload the parent HTML page it is embedded in?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript

I have a flash app (SWF) running Flash 8 embedded in an HTML page. How do I get flash to reload the parent HTML page it is embedded in? I've tried using ExternalInterface to call a JavaScript function to reload the page but that doesn't seem to work.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 11):

Check the [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) in Action Script. Using this you can call any JavaScript function in your code:

```
  if (ExternalInterface.available)
  {
    var result = ExternalInterface.call("reload");
  }
```

In the Embedding HTML code enter a JavaScript function:

```
  function reload()
  {
    document.location.reload(true);
    return true;
  }
```

This has the advantage that you can also check, if the function call succeeded and act accordingly. getUrl along with a call to JavaScript should not be used today anymore. It's an old hack.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

`getURL("javascript:location.reload(true)");`

Answer (score 4):

Simple one line solution.

```
ExternalInterface.call("document.location.reload", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty: This will work in most cases (without modifying the HTML page at all):

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.call("history.go", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Flash 10 you can do:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("path_to_page"), "_self");
```