# autorefresh flash player object?

Tags: javascript, flash

I created a flash movie player embedded into an html object. The flash player have an option of adding comments at any particular point of time.which is stored in database and is displayed in below the player object. Now the problem is when i added comment it is not by default showing on the webpage , after pressing F5 only, newly added comment is displaying.

is there any thing possible through auto-refresh after adding comments.

flash player

database comments

what happend is when we add marker then flash player redirects to some php file add that marker to database and then redirects back to the video-player file , starts playing video from that time where marker added.I want to call this function only after added to the database only. how can it is possible???

Answer (score 1):

Try calling an outside function using `ExternalInterface` when the SWF has new comments.

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
{
    var result = ExternalInterface.call("reload");
}
```

Found this answer:
[How do I get flash to reload the parent HTML page it is embedded in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96671/how-do-i-get-flash-to-reload-the-parent-html-page-it-is-embedded-in/211359#211359)